# Find the longest string

Tags: java

I am new to programming . Is this an efficient way to find the longest string using JAVA? Any feedback is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String [] letterlist = {"Hello" , "my" , "name" , "is" , "John" , "Smith"};
int length = letterlist.length; 
int currentchar; 
int nextchar; 
String getcurrentchar;
String getnextchar; 
String longest = " ";     

for(int index = 1; index <length; index++)
{

    getnextchar = letterlist[index];
    nextchar = getnextchar.length();
    getcurrentchar = letterlist[index-1];
    currentchar = getcurrentchar.length();


        if(nextchar > currentchar)
       {
        longest = getnextchar;

       }
   }
System.out.println(longest);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You only check if the current string is longer than the previous string. You don't necessarily find the longest. Also your variable naming and layout are very unclear.

Comment: No it is not an efficient way. Also the naming of your variables are wrong and do not represent their value and usage. The formatting is also bad, try to keep the indentations clean. Also try to be clean when posting code here, I know simple CTRL+C CTRL+V does not work nice.

Comment: What does efficient mean according to you? less number of lines or faster code or something else?

Comment: Did you try Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=find+the+longest+string+in+java&rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBIL770IL770&oq=Find+the+longest+string+in+j&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.6959j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: First  of all, String  variable  should not be named as char because it is confusing.  Then length  (number) is also named as char , another confusion.   And longest should be initialized to first String. Otherwise it will not work if  size  of array is 1.

Comment: So getcurrentstring i suppose not char. Is this correct Prabir Ghosh? Or previousstring  to everybody.

Comment: My professor discuss but not the whole programming etiquette. I stopped 4 years ago and i want to dvelop something like a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this in two lines of code:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(letterlist);
String longest = Arrays.stream(letterlist).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).get();
```

### Demo

Inspired by this Code Review question:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75807/finding-the-longest-string-and-its-length-using-java-streams

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using java 8 stream class, in order to learn correctly I would suggest you trying to iterate over the array of Strings and updating the value of the String. 
So as to get the number of characters of a string you can use the method length of the string class. Which returns you the number of characters of the string.
If you want to compare and update which is the longest string iteration over iteration, declare an empty String.

Comment: To iterate the array i would use for each loop correct?

Comment: Yeah but for each requires a lambda function, people who has just started needs to understand imperative paradigm,  from my point of view